# Cámara en espejo cuando se piden permisos para ingresar desde un navegador

Tags: html5, google-chrome, permisos, safari

Estoy diseñando una web con un plugin llamado THREECAMERA en el cual primero se abre desde el navegador (puede ser Chrome o Safari), y que al entrar le solicita al usuario permiso para ingresar a la cámara. El problema es que al darle los permisos, la cámara está en modo espejo, o sea que refleja todos los movimientos que hace el usuario.
Hay alguna manera de arreglar esto? Me ha pasado tanto en iOS como en Android. Estuve buscando y solo encontré la manera de arreglarlo desde la app nativa de la cámara, pero no me está sirviendo.
Mi sitio es el siguiente: https://www.kickads.mobi/ar/final/public/sunglasses/

El código del sitio:

```html
    <body onload="main()">
        <canvas width="600" height="600" id='detectedFaceCanvas'></canvas>
        <div id="takePhotoContainer" style="height: fit-content; bottom: 11%;">
            <img id="anteojo1" src="anteojo1.png" onclick="changeGlasses('blue')" style="height: 9%; margin-bottom: 3%;"/>
            <img id="takePhoto" src="boton_foto.png" onclick="takePhoto()" style="height: 13%;"/>
            <img id="anteojo2" src="anteojo2.png" onclick="changeGlasses('pink')" style="height: 9%; margin-bottom: 3%;"/>
        </div>
        <canvas width="600" height="600" id="takedPhoto"></canvas>
        <div id="share" style="bottom:10%; margin-bottom: 6%;"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Creo que es mejor que colocaras la codificacion que tienes, porque cualquiera puede pensar que esta promocionando tu sitio web.

Comment: Buena idea, ahora edito el pregunta y escrito el código!

Comment: En chrome parece tener un comportamiento normal.

Comment: @Angel es raro, porque a mi desde el iPhone ni siquiera me pide permisos, y no puedo in acceder a la cámara. Únicamente puedo hacerlo desde Safari, y cuando accede, me espeja la cámara.